# В чем ошибка

Tags: javascript

Есть код, долго думал почему он не работает, но ни как не решил проблему.

```
 function activate(){
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var div = document.getElementById('div');
    div.value=input.value;
    }
    <div id="id"></div>
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button onClick="activate()">
```

При нажатии на кнопку значение из `input` должно вставляться в  `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том что надо исправить `div.value=input.value;` где див надо писать не `value`, а `innerHTML`

Comment: Ой и вправду, заработало! спасибо Мих.

Comment: добавлю что свойство <b>value</b> доступно для любых елементов форм(текстареа, селект и т.д.)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего все, что относится к формам, реализовывать следующим образом:

```
form name="myform"
input name="myinput"
```

В итоге `document.myform.myinput.value`.

Comment: и чем же это лучше? ИМХО мягко говоря излишние телодвижения...

Comment: @AlexWindHope поддерживаю тебя!

Comment: А чем плохо? Толи дописывать input'у доп id или задействовать просто его имя? На вкус и цвет фломастеры разные ©

Comment: Это да :)<br>
И опять так, смотря какого размера форма, если инпутов много то тогда да, а так - излишние телодвижения...

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="id"></div>` обратите внимание, идентификатором слоя должен являться `div` судя по вашему коду, то есть вот так : `<div id="div"></div>`

Comment: пример абстрактный, ТС уже написал в коментах что проблема решена, к тому же уже выбран правельный ответ :)